# MongoDB C# Fluent Aggregate

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use the aggregate pipeline with fluent interfaces with no success, though I'm not receiving any error (all fields from result are null).

I have this **User** class:

```
public class User
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id;

    ...

    [BsonElement("last_access")]
    public DateTime LastAccess;
}
```

**Entity** class:

```
public class Entity
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id;

    ...

    [BsonElement("active")]
    public bool Active;

    [BsonElement("user_id")]
    public string UserId;
}
```

**UserLookup** class. This is used for the `$lookup`.

```
class UserLookup
{
    public int EntityCount;

    public IEnumerable<User> UsersData;
}
```

**UserResult** class. This is used for group and projection.

```
class UserResult
{
    public string UserId;

    public int EntityCount;

    public User UserData;
}
```

In my function, I have something like this:

```
IMongoCollection<Entity> entityCol = Database.Instance.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");
IMongoCollection<User> usersCol = Database.Instance.GetCollection<User>("users");

IAsyncCursor<UserResult> result = entityCol.Aggregate()
    .Match(e => e.Active)
    .Group(e => e.UserId, g => new UserResult {
        UserId = g.Key,
        EntityCount = g.Count()
    })
    .Lookup<UserResult, User, UserLookup>(usersCol,
        lf => lf.UserId,  // localField. UserResult.UserId
        ff => ff.Id,      // foreignField. User.Id
        r => r.UsersData  // result. UserLookup.UsersData
    )
    .Project(p => new UserResult {
        UserId = p.UserId,
        EntityCount = p.EntityCount,
        UserData = p.UsersData.First()
    })
    .ToCursor();

while (result.MoveNext()) {
    foreach (var ur in result.Current) {
        // ur.UserId = null; ur.UserData = null; ur.EntityCount = 0;
    }
}
```

I don't receive any error, but `EntityCount` is always 0 and both `UserId` and `UserData` are null. Basically, what I want is:

1. Get all entities that are active (`Match`).
2. Group them by user id (`Group`).
3. Lookup in the users collection to get the user data (`Lookup`).
4. Project the result to return a simple object with entity count and the user data (`Project`).

### ----- Update 1

Ok, after playing with mongo shell, I think I found the problem. It seems the mongo can't find entries by id with `ObjectId`, only with strings. This is weird, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8233427/2208678) and it seems it's possible to find using ObjectId (at least in the past).

In mongo shell, if I use `db.users.find({ _id: ObjectId("...") })` it returns nothing, but with `db.users.find({ _id: "..." })` it returns the expected user.

I wrote that aggregate query from scratch to run on shell, here it is:

```
db.entities.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "active": "true",
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id" : {
                $toString: "$user_id"
            },
            "EntityCount": { "$sum" : 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "UsersData"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "EntityCount": "$EntityCount",
            "UserData": {
                "$arrayElemAt": ["$UsersData", 0]
            },
        }
    },
    { $limit: 2 }
])
```

Note in the **$group** stage that I'm converting the user id to string. Won't work if I use `"_id": "$user_id"`.

The last stage `$limit` is just there to not blow out the console, making it easier to read the result.

This query executes perfectly fine.

#### Back to C#

This is the final query that C# driver uses:

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "active": true,
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$user_id",
            "EntityCount": {
                "$sum":1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "users_data"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "UserId": "$user_id",
            "EntityCount": "$EntityCount",
            "UserData": {
                "$arrayElemAt": ["$user_data", 0]
            },
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
]
```

I don't know why, but at the **$group** stage, the `UserId` field it's being ignored (this explains why it's always null in the result). Also, you can note that the `_id` is being set to 0 in the **$lookup** stage.

I renamed the field `UserId` from `UserResult` to `Id` and added the attribute `[BsonElement("_id")]`.

Now,I get both user id and entity count in the result, but the `UserData` is still null.

Comment: Have you established a Mongodb connection to the MongoDB data? And are you using the Newtonsoft.Json.Bson and MongoDB libraries?

Comment: @IliassNassibane The connection is fine. The nuget version of MongoDB.Driver is 2.9.2. My mongo server is 4.2.3. All my operations is running fine, except for this aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query form, that works>

```
IEnumerable<UserResult> result = entityCol.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Active).ToLookup(x => x.UserId)
    .Select(x => new UserResult {EntityCount = x.Count(), UserId = x.Key}).Join(usersCol.AsQueryable(),
        x => x.UserId, x => x.Id,
        (userResult, user) => new UserResult
            {EntityCount = userResult.EntityCount, UserData = user, UserId = userResult.UserId});

foreach (var ur in result)
{
    // ur.UserId = null; ur.UserData = null; ur.EntityCount = 0;
}
```

Your suspection for ObjectId - string conversion not working in Grouping is correct.

this works:

```
public class User
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id;

    [BsonElement("last_access")]
    public DateTime LastAccess;
}

public class Entity
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonId]
    public string Id;

    [BsonElement("active")]
    public bool Active;

    [BsonElement("user_id")]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string UserId;
}

class UserLookup
{
    public int EntityCount;

    public User[] UsersData;

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id;
}

class UserResult
{
    public string UserId;

    public int EntityCount;

    public User UserData;
}
```

This way it works>

```
IAsyncCursor<UserResult> result = entityCol.Aggregate()
    .Match(e => e.Active)
    .Group(e => e.UserId, g => new UserResult
    {
        UserId = g.Key,
        EntityCount = g.Count(),
    })
    .Lookup(usersCol,
        lf => lf.UserId,  // localField. UserResult.UserId
        ff => ff.Id,      // foreignField. User.Id
        (UserLookup r) => r.UsersData  // result. UserLookup.UsersData
    )
    .Project(p => new UserResult
    {
        UserId = p.UsersData.First().Id,
        EntityCount = p.EntityCount,
        UserData = p.UsersData.First()
    })
    .ToCursor();
```

Comment: I need to add `entityIds` even if I don't need it? I will test later, it's late here. I updated my question with tests with mongo shell.

Comment: @Kiritonito reworked the query. No need for `entityIds` where it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue resides in this

```
IAsyncCursor<UserResult> result = entity.Aggregate()
```

It should refer to the entity collection you made, entityCol.

```
IAsyncCursor<UserResult> result = entityCol.Aggregate()
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I'm already using Aggregate from `entityCol` in my real code (I wrote the code from question from scratch, to make it clean and clear). I will update the code.