# Why can't I find documents based on ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, fastapi

So I have some documents with a format like this:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee5816238c")
account_id: 371138
limit: 9000
products: Array
}
```

And I tried to query with this code in Python:

```
doc = col.find({"_id": ObjectId("5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee5816238c")})
```

But it always raises ValueError: ObjectId is not iterable. Was wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: Refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233014/how-do-i-search-for-an-object-by-its-objectid-in-the-mongo-console, that might solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `find()` syntax looks correct; so maybe it's something else; see if you can get the code snippet to work:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.json_util import ObjectId

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
col = db.mycollection

col.insert_one({
    '_id': ObjectId("5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee5816238c"),
    'account_id': 371138,
    'limit': 9000,
    'products': 'Array'
})

doc = col.find({"_id": ObjectId("5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee5816238c")})
print(list(doc))
```

prints:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee5816238c'), 'account_id': 371138, 'limit': 9000, 'products': 'Array'}]
```

Comment: Good idea, will try it

Answer (score 0):

use dictionary instead of this mess. Define it like that and read documentation on how to work with dictionaries. Code:-

```
details={
    "_id": ObjectId("5ca4bbc7a2dd94ee5816238c"),
    "account_id": 371138,
    "limit": 9000,
    "products": Array
}
```

Comment: Is there any way without modifying the mongodb database?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge about this subject as I am at the beginning stage of learning python. We have to wait for some expert to answer this. Sorry!