# MongoDB Finding "_id" in query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am developing a Node.js web app that provides CRUD operations using MongoDB along with Heroku. I am able to view what is inside my query with the snippet

```
//supposed to get all EMRs from our collection
app.get('/emr', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        client.connect();
        console.log('Connected to DB');
        const collection = client.db("cmps_example").collection("emrs");

        var query = { };
        console.log(query);
        const result = await collection.find(req.body).toArray();
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result)
        client.close();
    }
    catch(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    console.log('Done with Endpoint: All EMR resources');
});
```

Output:

```
[{"_id":"6273f484d8537384a2975d4a","name":"Zach","StudentId":"0518049"},{"_id":"627407a488f9e98da126c3bf","name":"Joe","StudentId":"0682298"}]
```

Knowing what I have in the query, I want to be able to get a single document out of it using its object id(_id). I am having trouble with this. Any tips on why my code is not doing so?

```
//supposed to get single EMR from our collection
app.get('/emr/:_id', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        client.connect();
        console.log('Connected to DB');
        const collection = client.db("cmps_example").collection("emrs");

        var query = { };
        console.log(query);
        const result = await collection.findOne(req.params.id).toArray();
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result)
        client.close();
    }
    catch(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    console.log('Done with Endpoint');
});
```

Output:

```
{ }
```

Comment: For your first query, what is `req.body`?  For the second query, what is `req.params.id`?

Comment: It's an express.js property. They're used by the client to send data to the server

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit.  Would you print them and include them in your question?

Comment: For sure. I just edited and added the result of the two endpoints. The first I get everything in the query, but second I am trying to get 1 using the _id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I search for an object by its ObjectId in the mongo console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233014/how-do-i-search-for-an-object-by-its-objectid-in-the-mongo-console)

Comment: @GarrettCrawford For your first query, what is the **value** of `req.body`?  For the second query, what is the **value** of `req.params.id`?

Comment: The first query  value I posted above in the output.. The second query I am getting null for the value of req.params.id

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(req.body);` and `console.log(req.params.id)`?