# ObjectId id not of Function Type

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, bson

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tq6v.png

```
import {MongoClient, ObjectId} from "mongodb";
async function handler(req, res){
    if(req.method === "POST"){
        const data = req.body;
        const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongoDB URL")
        const db = client.db();
        const postItCollection = db.collection("postIts");
        const result = await postItCollection.updateOne({_id: ObjectId(data.id)}, {$set:{positionX:data.y, positionY:data.x}});
        console.log(result);
        client.close();
        res.status(201).json({message:"success"})
    }
}
export default handler;
```

- I'm attaching a picture just in case.
  I've been looking for it for three hours, but I can't find the answer....
  I don't think there's anyone on Earth who has the same problem as me....
- I tried installed the "bson-objectid" library.
  and "mongoose" Types property

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Types;
```

I've tried it, but I've seen same error of "method expression is not of function type"

Help me, all the masters of the earth.

From Newbie.

```
import {MongoClient, ObjectId} from "mongodb";
async function handler(req, res){
    if(req.method === "POST"){
        const data = req.body;
        const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongoDB URL")
        const db = client.db();
        const postItCollection = db.collection("postIts");
        const result = await postItCollection.updateOne({_id: data.id}, {$set:{positionX:data.y, positionY:data.x}});                                // <= if i not use ObjectId
        console.log(result);
        client.close();
        res.status(201).json({message:"success"})
    }
}
export default handler;
```

- if I not use ObjectId I've got success messages but can't find id...
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJOQH.png
- I just want to find id in mongoDB and change data

PS. How can I see the image right away instead of the URL?
I looked at the other answers and did the same thing, but only the URL came out...

Answer (score 0):

Oh i find Answer...!
It's `new` operation...

[How do I search for an object by its ObjectId in the mongo console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233014/how-do-i-search-for-an-object-by-its-objectid-in-the-mongo-console?rq=1)

```
const result = await postItCollection.updateOne({_id: new ObjectId(data.id)}, {$set:{positionX:data.y, positionY:data.x}});
```